# GoogleNet Implantation ValueError: Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to implement GoogleNet inception network to classify images for classification project that I am working on, I used the same code before but with AlexNet network and the training was fine, but once I changed the network to GoogleNet architecture the code kept throwing the following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 3 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: [array([[0., 1.],
       [1., 0.],
       [1., 0.],
       [1., 0.],
       [1., 0.],
       [1., 0.],
       [0., 1.],
       [1., 0.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., ...
```

here is my complete code:

```
import keras
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Dropout, Dense, Flatten, Conv2D
from keras.layers import GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.layers import AveragePooling2D, MaxPool2D, concatenate

Data = 'data/train/'
batch_size = 64
NUM_EPOCHS = 20


def inception_module(x,
                 filters_1x1,
                 filters_3x3_reduce,
                 filters_3x3,
                 filters_5x5_reduce,
                 filters_5x5,
                 filters_pool_proj,
                 name=None):
conv_1x1 = Conv2D(filters_1x1, (1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_init,
                  bias_initializer=bias_init)(x)

conv_3x3 = Conv2D(filters_3x3_reduce, (1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_init,
                  bias_initializer=bias_init)(x)
conv_3x3 = Conv2D(filters_3x3, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_init,
                  bias_initializer=bias_init)(conv_3x3)

conv_5x5 = Conv2D(filters_5x5_reduce, (1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_init,
                  bias_initializer=bias_init)(x)
conv_5x5 = Conv2D(filters_5x5, (5, 5), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_init,
                  bias_initializer=bias_init)(conv_5x5)

pool_proj = MaxPool2D((3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same')(x)
pool_proj = Conv2D(filters_pool_proj, (1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_init,
                   bias_initializer=bias_init)(pool_proj)

output = concatenate([conv_1x1, conv_3x3, conv_5x5, pool_proj], axis=3, name=name)

return output



kernel_init = keras.initializers.glorot_uniform()
bias_init = keras.initializers.Constant(value=0.2)

input_layer = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))

x = Conv2D(64, (7, 7), padding='same', strides=(2, 2), activation='relu', name='conv_1_7x7/2',)(input_layer)
x = MaxPool2D((3, 3), padding='same', strides=(2, 2), name='max_pool_1_3x3/2')(x)
x = Conv2D(64, (1, 1), padding='same', strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', name='conv_2a_3x3/1')(x)
x = Conv2D(192, (3, 3), padding='same', strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', name='conv_2b_3x3/1')(x)
x = MaxPool2D((3, 3), padding='same', strides=(2, 2), name='max_pool_2_3x3/2')(x)

x = inception_module(x,
                 filters_1x1=64,
                 filters_3x3_reduce=96,
                 filters_3x3=128,
                 filters_5x5_reduce=16,
                 filters_5x5=32,
                 filters_pool_proj=32,
                 name='inception_3a')

x = inception_module(x,
                 filters_1x1=128,
                 filters_3x3_reduce=128,
                 filters_3x3=192,
                 filters_5x5_reduce=32,
                 filters_5x5=96,
                 filters_pool_proj=64,
                 name='inception_3b')

x = MaxPool2D((3, 3), padding='same', strides=(2, 2), name='max_pool_3_3x3/2')(x)

x = inception_module(x,
                 filters_1x1=192,
                 filters_3x3_reduce=96,
                 filters_3x3=208,
                 filters_5x5_reduce=16,
                 filters_5x5=48,
                 filters_pool_proj=64,
                 name='inception_4a')


x1 = AveragePooling2D((5, 5), strides=3)(x)
x1 = Conv2D(128, (1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu')(x1)
x1 = Flatten()(x1)
x1 = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x1)
x1 = Dropout(0.7)(x1)
x1 = Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='auxilliary_output_1')(x1)

x = inception_module(x,
                 filters_1x1=160,
                 filters_3x3_reduce=112,
                 filters_3x3=224,
                 filters_5x5_reduce=24,
                 filters_5x5=64,
                 filters_pool_proj=64,
                 name='inception_4b')

x = inception_module(x,
                 filters_1x1=128,
                 filters_3x3_reduce=128,
                 filters_3x3=256,
                 filters_5x5_reduce=24,
                 filters_5x5=64,
                 filters_pool_proj=64,
                 name='inception_4c')

x = inception_module(x,
                 filters_1x1=112,
                 filters_3x3_reduce=144,
                 filters_3x3=288,
                 filters_5x5_reduce=32,
                 filters_5x5=64,
                 filters_pool_proj=64,
                 name='inception_4d')


x2 = AveragePooling2D((5, 5), strides=3)(x)
x2 = Conv2D(128, (1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu')(x2)
x2 = Flatten()(x2)
x2 = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x2)
x2 = Dropout(0.7)(x2)
x2 = Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='auxilliary_output_2')(x2)

x = inception_module(x,
                 filters_1x1=256,
                 filters_3x3_reduce=160,
                 filters_3x3=320,
                 filters_5x5_reduce=32,
                 filters_5x5=128,
                 filters_pool_proj=128,
                 name='inception_4e')

x = MaxPool2D((3, 3), padding='same', strides=(2, 2), name='max_pool_4_3x3/2')(x)

x = inception_module(x,
                 filters_1x1=256,
                 filters_3x3_reduce=160,
                 filters_3x3=320,
                 filters_5x5_reduce=32,
                 filters_5x5=128,
                 filters_pool_proj=128,
                 name='inception_5a')

x = inception_module(x,
                 filters_1x1=384,
                 filters_3x3_reduce=192,
                 filters_3x3=384,
                 filters_5x5_reduce=48,
                 filters_5x5=128,
                 filters_pool_proj=128,
                 name='inception_5b')

x = GlobalAveragePooling2D(name='avg_pool_5_3x3/1')(x)

x = Dropout(0.4)(x)

x = Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='output')(x)


model = Model(input_layer, [x, x1, x2], name='inception_v1')
model.compile(SGD(lr=0.01), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])


train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                               validation_split=0.2,
                               dtype=None,)


train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(Data,
                                             target_size=(224, 224),
                                             batch_size=batch_size,
                                             class_mode='categorical',
                                             subset='training'
                                                )


validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(Data,
                                        target_size=(224, 224),
                                        batch_size=batch_size,
                                        class_mode='categorical',
                                        subset='validation'
                                                     )



Model = model.fit_generator(generator=train_generator, steps_per_epoch=train_generator.samples // batch_size,
                              epochs=NUM_EPOCHS, verbose=1, shuffle=True, 
validation_data=validation_generator,
                              validation_steps=validation_generator.samples // batch_size)
```

Comment: I guess you're trying to train this model on a 10-class classification problem. If that's the case, the issue is the way you've defined the `output` in `model = Model(input_layer, [x, x1, x2], name='inception_v1')`. `output` should be a vector of length 10, but you're passing a list of three vectors, each of length 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GoogleNet is different than Alexnet, in GoogleNet your model has 3 outputs, 1 main and 2 auxiliary outputs connected in intermediate layers during training:

```
outputs = [main, aux1, aux2]
```

Such as:

```
model = Model(inputs = X_input, outputs = [main, aux1, aux2])
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
          loss_weights={'main': 1.0, 'aux1': 0.3, 'aux2': 0.3},
          optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Your model structure seems working but the issue arises from data handling.
To overcome this issue you may create your own custom generator:

```
def Custom_generator(generator, image_dir, batch_size, image_size, subset):
My_Data= generator.flow_from_directory(
    image_dir,
    target_size=(image_size, image_size),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical',
    subset=subset)

while True:
    My_Data_next = My_Data.next()
    # this returns image batch and 3 sets one-hot vectors of lables
    yield My_Data_next[0], [My_Data_next[1], My_Data_next[1], My_Data_next[1]]
```

Code for data handling in your case:

```
image_size = (224, 224)
image_dir= 'data/train/'
batch_size = 64
NUM_EPOCHS = 20

# Get the Data and split 20% for validation.
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, validation_split=0.2)

# Your Custom Generator
def custom_generator(generator, image_dir, batch_size, image_size, subset):
My_Data= generator.flow_from_directory(
    image_dir,
    target_size=image_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical',
    subset=subset)
while True:
    My_Data_next = My_Data.next()
    # this returns image batch and 3 sets one-hot vectors of lables
    yield My_Data_next[0], [My_Data_next[1], My_Data_next[1], My_Data_next[1]]
       
train_generator = custom_generator(
    train_datagen,
    image_dir=image_dir,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    image_size=image_size,
    subset='training')
     
validation_generator = custom_generator(
    train_datagen,
    image_dir=image_dir,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    image_size=image_size,
    subset='validation')
```

Hope this solves the error.